# Joining lists with unequal data

Tags: r

I have 3 different lists in R as follows:

```
dput(emp_id)
dput(employee)
dput(roles)

list("E1201", "E2231", "E3451")
list("John", "James", "Jonie")
c("district manager", "cashier", "food preparer", "cashier")
```

I am trying to make it into a dataframe as follows:

```
EMP id   Employee    Roles 
E1201    John        ["district manager"]
E2231    James       ["cashier", "food manager"]
E3451    Jonie       []
```

I tried

```
df = cbind(dd, de, di)
```

But it says that the arguments imply different rows. May i know whether there is any methods that can be used?

Comment: Can you please share the `dput()` of your lists so we can copy/paste it into R to test possible solutions.

Comment: Maybe try `data.frame(I(dd), de, di)` or `list2DF(list(dd, de, di))`

Answer (score 0):

You can extend your vectors as follows:

```
rows <- max(length(di), length(de), length(dd))

dd <- c(dd, rep(NA, rows - length(dd)
de <- c(de, rep(NA, rows - length(de)
di <- c(di, rep(NA, rows - length(di)
```

If you know which one is the biggest one(s), you can tweak it accordingly